# perl check existence of a hash key when there is value at the same level in strict refs check

Tags: perl, hash, key, strict

For the following code with strict check, it will raise an error.

```
use strict;
my $a;
my $b;
my $c;

my %database;
$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'} = 'e';
$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}{'d'} = 'f';
foreach my $a (keys %database){
  foreach my $b (keys %{$database{$a}}){
    foreach my $c (keys %{$database{$a}{$b}}){
      if (exists $database{$a}{$b}{$c}{'d'}){print "success!\n";}
    }
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
Can't use string ("e") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 8.
```

Value 'e' and key 'd' is at the same level. When "exists" tries to find key d, the debugger will find there are values at the same level and raise the error, because 'e' is not a key to check.
How do I solve it when keeping the structure of hash and the use of strict?

Yes it would raise an error at line 8. Actually another one created this hash without strict in one file and when I wrote another part in another file, I have strict and it raises such a problem.

Comment: Per first assignment, `$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}` is a string (`e`) so in second assignement you try to use the same variable (which is a string) as an hash to store the pair `('d', 'f')` which can not work as the error message tells you, before even trying the first `foreach`. You will need to revisit your data structure.

Comment: Avoid using `my $a;` and `my $b;` as `$a` and `$b` are kind of reserved Perl variables and you might have suprises.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek OKOK, I will not use such reserved values any more. I just wanna make an example...XD

Answer (score 4):

The following stores a string in `$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}`:

```
$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'} = 'e';
```

But the following expects `$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}` to be a reference:

```
$database{'a'}{'b'}{'c'}{'d'} = 'f';
```

Assuming you can have values at any level, you need to change your data structure to something like the following:

```
$database{a}{children}{b}{children}{c}{value} = 'e';
$database{a}{children}{b}{children}{c}{children} = 'f';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to not do the check unless the c-level is a hash, just check that:

```
if (ref $database{$a}{$b}{$c} ne 'HASH') {
    print "not a hash\n";
}
elsif (exists $database{$a}{$b}{$c}{'d'}){
    print "success!\n";
}
```

Comment: See ikegami's answer for a data structure to allow strings and hashes at the same "level"